# Multimedia playback control and data flow for google-tv

Tags: android, google-tv

I just wanted to know if there are any documents or flow diagrams explaining the control and data flow for multimedia playback on google-tv. i am aware of the same on the mobile part(awesome player -> omx_codec and so on), but i think the same does not apply for google-tv  multimedia playback.
any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We are moving to OMX.  The next release announced at I/O will be OMX based.  Please look at [Google I/O 2012 - Get your Content on Google TV](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bNbKpUqkOso) for more information.

Additionally - the flow has always been the same as Android.  However, you might not see some method invocations as there is a bug in current releases.  This will be fixed in the next release.  If you need a specific item, please ask.